# Change the column name in join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My Associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :women, foreign_key: "cell_id"
end

class Woman < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users, foreign_key: "cellid"
end
```

This is my join

```
@all = Woman.joins(:users)
```

And I have the Select

```
SELECT "women".* FROM "women" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."cellid" = "women"."id"
```

But I need

```
SELECT "women".* FROM "women" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."cellid" = "women"."cell_id"
```

How I do this?

Comment: what is you ror select statement in the controller and how do you call it?

Comment: Making a mobile dating app?

Comment: women = Woman.all - in my woman.rb controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people would write the join in raw SQL and encapsulate it within a scope:

in woman.rb

```
scope :join_women_on_cell_id, lambda {
  joins('INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."cellid" = "women"."cell_id"')
}
```

Comment: Caveat: Do you really want raw SQL in your RoR code? Most Rails apps have it, but you can also generate it using a DSL like Arel or Squeel. I've looked into them, but not found them to give me much power over raw SQL, except in the case that database independence is crucial.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it won't work with nested joins.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this solution, but it was the easiest and best way to do it at the time. RoR might have moved on since then, so I would caution anyone reading this not to trust a 11yr old answer.